# How to create new calculated columns in pandas and remove original?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe 'df' that has:

```
name a b
greg 1 1
george 2 2
giles 3 3
giovanni 4 5
```

I want to run this dataframe through a calcuate function to create new columns: c and d such that I get the following resulting dataframe:

```
name c d
greg 11 21
george 12 22
giles 13 23
giovanni 14 24
```

Currently, my code is as follows:

My calcluate function:

```
def calculate(row):
   return row['a']+10, row['b']+20
```

My function to modify the dataframe:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(calculate, axis=1)
```

The resulting dataframe I am getting is this:

```
name a b c
greg 1 1 (11, 21)
george 2 2(12, 22)
giles 3 3 (13, 23)
giovanni 4 4 (14, 24)
```

How do I get my dataframe to look like:

```
name c d
greg 11 21
george 12 22
giles 13 23
giovanni 14 24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row iteration is very slow.  You are much better off doing something like the following:

```
df['c'] = df.a + 10
df['d'] = df.b + 20
df.drop(['a', 'b'], axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

To implement your method, however, you would need to do this:

```
df['c'], df['d'] = zip(*df.apply(calculate, axis=1))
>>> df
       name  a  b   c   d
0      greg  1  1  11  21
1    george  2  2  12  22
2     giles  3  3  13  23
3  giovanni  4  5  14  25
```

Comment: What if the calculation of the new 'c' and 'd' values were dependent on both 'a' and 'b'? Could you show a sample of that? Meaning, the calculation requires passing in 'a' and 'b' as input. to generate the new 'c' and 'd'. (For example, c = a - b, and d = a + b).

Comment: `df['c'] = df.a - df.b` and `df['d'] = df.a + df.b`